# tar --newer -N --after-date ignorance

Tags: increment, tar

I trie to create incremental tar archives on a tape device.
The problem I have is that the `--newer | -N | --after-date` seems to be ignored for some reason I cannot understand.

- I'm not talking about directories as I understand tar will only look at dates of files, dirs will always be included.
- The `--listed-incremental` parameter is giving me inconsistent results so I cannot use that either.

An example will probably explain more about my issue:

Here's the listing from the directory I try to tar with the `--newer` parameter:

```
[root@ba-backup software]# ls -lh nexenta/
total 600M
-rw-------. 1 lieven lieven 387K Nov 27  2013 doc_3.1_automaticinstallation-viapxe-    boot-3-1.pdf
drwxr-xr-x  2 lieven lieven 4.0K Jul 10 12:26 newdir
-rw-r--r--  1 lieven lieven    0 Jul 10 12:26 newfile
-rw-r--r--. 1 lieven lieven 599M Sep 26  2013 NexentaStor-Community-3.1.5-GA.iso
-rw-------. 1 lieven lieven 280K Nov 27  2013 NexentaStor-InstallationGuide-3.1.x.pdf
```

This is my tar command and it's result:

```
tar --totals --atime-preserve=system --index-file=nex.tar.index --label nextar --newer 20131010 -cvf nex.tar -C /data/samba/users/lieven/software/nexenta/ .
tar: Option --after-date: Treating date `20131010' as 2013-10-10 00:00:00
Total bytes written: 628705280 (600MiB, 53MiB/s)

cat nex.tar.index 
nextar
./
./doc_3.1_automaticinstallation-viapxe-boot-3-1.pdf
./NexentaStor-Community-3.1.5-GA.iso
./newdir/
./NexentaStor-InstallationGuide-3.1.x.pdf
./newfile
```

As you can see it correctly converts the date to the same date I want to use in the example, it should not archive the iso file which is from sept-2013 and newer says it wants file that are newer than 10 october 2013 which is in fact all except the iso.

To make things mysterious, it works if I want to have all newer than 2014-07-01 which are the newfile and newdir:

```
tar --totals --atime-preserve=system --index-file=nex.tar.index --label nextar --newer 20140701 -cvf nex.tar -C /data/samba/users/lieven/software/nexenta/ .
tar: Option --after-date: Treating date `20140701' as 2014-07-01 00:00:00
tar: ./doc_3.1_automaticinstallation-viapxe-boot-3-1.pdf: file is unchanged; not dumped
tar: ./NexentaStor-Community-3.1.5-GA.iso: file is unchanged; not dumped
tar: ./NexentaStor-InstallationGuide-3.1.x.pdf: file is unchanged; not dumped
Total bytes written: 10240 (10KiB, 6.7MiB/s)
```

here's some info about the iso file which should already been excluded in the first run:

```
stat nexenta/NexentaStor-Community-3.1.5-GA.iso 
  File: `nexenta/NexentaStor-Community-3.1.5-GA.iso'
  Size: 628011008   Blocks: 1226592    IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 901h/2305d  Inode: 112466146   Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (  500/  lieven)   Gid: (  500/  lieven)
Access: 2014-07-10 11:42:17.501325399 +0200
Modify: 2013-09-26 13:35:07.000000000 +0200
Change: 2014-03-25 15:53:20.594456047 +0100
```

I was kinda hoping that the access time would explain it but it's not looking at this or it should have always included all files in both tests.

Does anybody know what is causing this strange dat behaviour?

As a sidenote, I tried different date formats with `YYYY-mm-dd` or the `$(date)` command but none did change the behaviour.

thanks.